# String with Æ Ø or Å is removed when using htmlspecialchars or htmlentities

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I simply cannot figure out why my strings are being removed when I try to echo them out when they contain Æ Ø or Å.

I have tried both:

```
htmlspecialchars ($row ['contact_person'])
htmlentities ($row ['contact_person'])
```

I the contact persons name is Peter Mørk for example, the string is simply not showing. If I remove htmlspecialchars or htmlentities the string is echoed out fine.

Shouldn't the string just be encoded, instead of removed?

What do I need to do?

Comment: Have you looked the documentation for htmlspecialchars? Returning an empty string is a documented behavior. There are options like `ENT_IGNORE` and `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` that change this behavior.

Comment: If I use ENT_SUBSTITUTE my ø will turn into: ¿½

Comment: Ah, figured it out. I need to add: ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'ISO-8859-1'. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a third parameter to [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) which changes the character set.
This works, for example:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('Peter Mørk',null,'ISO-8859-1');
```